# Is there a way to present a Datazoom component on ECharts of type graph?

Tags: echarts

I'm using Echarts to present a chart of type "graph" but I couldn't find a way to present a datazoom component. All the examples in the documentation are on different types.

When I tried to add either of the the datazooms "slider" or "inside" nothing showed up.

Comment: not quite sure I understand the question but series type 'graph' has the [roam property](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-graph.roam) to enable zooming. The datazoom components are defined on axes which dont apply to graph.

Comment: Apperently you can define a graph on a grid like in [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph-grid). Now its possible to define a datazoom component on the axes.

Comment: yes, roam is working and I can zoom using the mouse scrolling

Comment: But, I can't set grid since I use "force" layout

Comment: If you really need a slider you could implement one yourself using the [zoom property](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-graph.zoom) of the graph.

Comment: Yes... that is what I ended up doing. I really hoped the built in functionality would work.